# Páginas em ASP.NET continuam em execução após mudar de página?

Tags: asp.net

O método [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) possui um parâmetro em um de seus *overloads* chamado `endResponse` que quando `true` indica que a página atual deve ser finalizada depois do redirecionamento.

Isso significa que quando realizo um redirecionamento de página (mudo de página) a página anterior ainda estará ocupando espaço em algum lugar? Seria então uma boa prática, sempre utilizar `true` nesse parâmetro quando não for mais utilizar a página atual?

Answer (score 9):

Esse [blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect) (em inglês) explica com detalhes a situação do `endResponse`. Em suma, o comportamento de se **encerrar o thread** após um redirect foi considerado um erro de projeto, algo que é prejudicial à eficiência do ASP [clássico] mas que foi mantido por questões de compatibilidade. O método recomendado para códigos novos é sempre usar `false`, nunca usar `true` ou nada (i.e. usar a versão sem o segundo parâmetro - que por padrão assume `true`).

Se você deseja finalizar a renderização após esse redirect (ou seja, não há mais nada de útil para seu código fazer em seguida) use `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.

> Isso significa que quando realizo um redirecionamento de página (mudo de página) a página anterior ainda estará ocupando espaço em algum lugar?

O thread usado para renderizar a página anterior ainda existe em algum  lugar, e pode ser reutilizado para servir futuros requests. Se você usa `endResponse true` esse thread é destruído e recriado (operação custosa), daí o problema de performance.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você passa `true` no segundo parâmetro ele chama o `Response.End` que causa uma exceção. E [segundo a documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isso é mais prejudicial a performance do que passar `false` (ou nada).

> This exception has a **detrimental effect on Web application performance**, which is why passing false for the endResponse parameter is recommended.

Caso o método `End` falhe em lançar uma exceção, ele vai tentar enviar todo o buffer para o cliente de forma síncrona que também é prejudicial para performance.